# How to share phpMyAdmin DBMS to another computer outside network (LAN)?

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, phpmyadmin, rdbms

I am very new in this environment and currently having this difficulty to share my DBMS work to my teammates. Tried to find solutions but mostly it was a solution if it's from the same network. Is there any way (in details) how can I share it from outside network?

Comment: Your question is ambiguous to me, are you trying to grant access to only phpMyAdmin from outside the network, or to MySQL/MariaDB directly? phpMyAdmin is a web-based graphical tool for administrators to manage a database, but if you're using any kind of application you'll want to give access to MySQL/MariaDB directly since phpMyAdmin is not an access API. Do your teammates need to access MySQL/MariaDB (port 3306) or phpMyAdmin (web based, so typically port 80 or 443)?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up a VPN/Proxy server on your LAN network and then your teammates will connect to that VPN/Proxy server externally for accessing the phpMyAdmin DBMS as a VPN or Proxy would simulate your teammates network connection to be as if they were on the same network as the phpMyAdmin DBMS, which is only accessible on LAN.

This will undoubtedly be the most secure method of connecting to the server and also without making too many changes to the configuration of the phpMyAdmin DBMS, which could be messed up in the process of modifying all the configuration files and be quite a hassle.